# Unterschied zwischen "zum Tragen kommen" und "zur Geltung kommen"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen generellen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wendungen?

> Dabei kommen auch die visuellen Reize besonders gut zum Tragen, die zudem in wirkungsvollem Kontrast zum (...) stehen
>
> Die Vorteile des Gerätes kommen erst dann zur Geltung, wenn...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn etwas zum Tragen kommt, dann wird es wirksam. Kommt es hingegen nur zur Geltung, dann erscheint es lediglich.

Answer (score 1):

> *zum Tragen kommen* - effektiv werden, zur Wirkung kommen
>
> *zur Geltung kommen* - vorteilhaft erscheinen; seine Vorzüge offenbaren